# How to execute find command with Powershell

Tags: windows, git, powershell

I'm learning Git Internals https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

When I try to execute this command on Windows (using cmder a better console http://cmder.net/)

```
find .git/objects
```

I get an error

[image]

What should I do instead ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`find.exe` in Windows is *not* the equivalent of `find` in linux.

The equivalent of `find [startpath]` in PowerShell would be:

```
Get-ChildItem [startpath] -Name
```

and in `cmd.exe`, it would be:

```
dir /B [startpath]
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `dir /S`?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

For an equivalent of:

```
find foo -type f
```

... I use:

```
Get-Children foo -Name -Recurse -File | % { $_ -replace "\\", "/" }
```

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, there is no command `Get-Children` in Powershell (or at least it does not autocomplete to anything like that in the shell).

Answer (score 3):

Use the `FullName` attribute, otherwise it will not show the full name if the path is long:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\dist\work' -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' -Filter "objects").FullName
C:\dist\work\bam-client\.git\objects
C:\dist\work\bam-extras\.git\objects
:
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search **recursively** down the directory tree using **wildcards** (a very common pattern when using `find`), try:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Filter *foobar* -Recurse <path>
```